# Format text within a script

Tags: jquery, formatting

Hi I have a typewriter script as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.example4').typeIt({
     whatToType: ["Introduction Thesis xy", "2"],
     typeSpeed: 150,
     breakLines: false
});
})
```

I want to make Introduction bold and have a linebreak before Thesis xy, how can I do that?

Comment: Where is code for `typeIt()`? What library are you using? Also, this question looks quite unclear to me.

Comment: here is all code https://jsfiddle.net/3mdm5y9k/1/

Comment: Here is your updated code https://jsfiddle.net/3mdm5y9k/4/

Comment: but that isn`t what i was asking for. How can I have a linebreak after "introduction"? <br> for obvious reasons, but i don t know how else to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using html with your version of typeit js is not possible. But if you change version to 5.5.0 then it's possible to in this way.

You could use this CDN for loading typeit js

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typeit@5.5.0/dist/typeit.min.js"></script>
```

```js
new TypeIt('.example4', {
  strings: ["<b>Introduction</b>", "Thesis xy 2"],
  speed: 150
});
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Nimbus";
  src: url("fonts/Nimbus.woff") format("woff");
}

body * {
  font-family: 'Nimbus';
  font-size: 25px;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Customizable-Terminal-Text-Effect-TypeIt/dist/typeit.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/typeit@5.5.0/dist/typeit.min.js"></script>

<p class="example4"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `breakLines: true` and you can add necessary html in the text to make `Introduction` bold and add a new line before `Thesis xy`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.example4').typeIt({
     whatToType: ["<b>Introduction</b><br>Thesis xy", "2"],
     typeSpeed: 150,
     breakLines: true
   });
})
```